# what happens behind the seen on closing window in C# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, object, memory-leaks, reference

I am passing object of Window1 as reference to Window2 using this. Then I close Window1 and try to show Window1 using button click from Window2.
I am getting an error which is often possible with with any developer in wpf. Error is: **Cannot set visibility or call Show, ShowDialog after a window has closed.**

**button click method in Window1.xaml.cs**
`{`
    `Window2 w2 = new Window2();` 
    `w2.w1Obj = this;`
    `w2.show();`
`}`

Then I close Window1.

**button click method in Window2.xaml.cs**
`{`
`w1Obj.testMethod();`
`this.w1Obj.show();`
`}`

Here `testMethod()` is executed well but when I want to show that window, it gets crashed. so I want to know what happens in memory or whatever to Window1 object when I closed that Window.? Is this memory leak.?

Comment: Well, it looks like you are closing a window and then attempting to call show on it, which you can't do, as the error message clearly states.

Comment: but why.? If i can execute a method of that class, then I could show that window too.

Comment: See Luca's answer below. The class instance isn't being disposed since you hold a reference to it, but after Close has been called it is no longer a working form that can be shown again.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to use Window.Hide() instead of Window.Close().

When Window.Close() is called:

> Closing a window causes the Closing event to be raised. If the Closing event isn't canceled, the following occurs:
>
> The Window is removed from Application.Windows (if an Application object exists).
>
> The Window is removed from the owner Window if the owner/owned relationship was established before the owned Window was shown and after the owner Window was opened.
>
> The Closed event is raised.
>
> Unmanaged resources created by the Window are disposed.
>
> If ShowDialog was called to show the Window, ShowDialog returns.
>
> Closing a Window causes any windows that it owns to be closed. Furthermore, closing a Window may cause an application to stop running depending on how the Application.ShutdownMode property is set.

You can find more on the Closing Event here [Closing Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.window.closing(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Window closing is not my issue. my concern is `testMethod()` is executed, but show() method generates error. Why so.? Is after closing window, that object is also removed from memory.?<br/> Or it ios bcz I have a reference and using it, i can not show a window.?

Comment: TestMethod() work fine beacause the object still exist, the Close() method doesn't destroy it. But you need to reinstantiate the window if u want to call the Show() method after the Close().